# vsts-agent in OpenShift

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure-devops

I run the agent in my machine and it works just perfect. Then I pushed my image to openshift, then I got some permission denied issue:
`./start.sh: line 19: /vsts/.token: Permission denied`

I tried to find how to give these permissions within OpenShift, but I was not able to find yet, someone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, running it as root and passing the permissions to the folder did the trick.

`USER root 
RUN chmod -R +x /vsts
RUN chmod -R g+rwX /vsts`